# Konica Minolta Bizhub C659 - Can't login with Admin Credentials without website timing out

Tags: printer

Just as the title says, i have a konica minolta bizhub c659 and i can access the portal fine even after clearing out my browser cache and its set to a static ip. i can maneuver through the website with no issues but I need to login with the admin credentials and when i try to enter the password and hit login the site times out and i've tried it on multiple computers. We've tried rebooting the printer. We don't want to factory reset the printer as that is a last resort because there is a ton of configuration done on this. Has anyone experienced this before? If so, any ideas on how to resolve it?

Also just for my own education... How does this password save? Is this printer portal an internal web server being hosted on the printer? Where are the credentials held and how are they held, in what format, and can we access them?

Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: “Is this printer portal an internal web server being hosted on the printer?” - That’s a safe assumption. What browsers have you used? Have you tried enabling some of the older SSL/TLS versions? Additionally, http or https?